# returning an array from an array prototype if there is any

Tags: javascript

Here is a working example of what I want to do:

```js
let value = " Have  you ever * looked*  sam [5, 6]";
// let value = " Have  you ever * looked*  sam"; // we may have this instead

// So far I need to check if there is []
if(value.includes('[')){

    const archiveGuidePure = value.substring(value.indexOf('['), value.length);
    value = value.replace(archiveGuidePure, "");
    const archiveGuide = JSON.parse(archiveGuidePure);
    console.log(archiveGuide);

}

console.log(value);
```

As you see we have a string in `value` and the string might have an array prototype at the very end of it. note that sometimes we want that array and sometimes we don't.

The code checks the `value` to see if there is an array.

if there is an array it removes the array and returns it as an array. if there is not an array at the end of `value` then nothing changes.

So far I need to check if there is a `[` sign otherwise I get an error which made my code ugly and in my mind a bad practice.

How do you do this without if statement?

Comment: I would say you already have the best what you got i believe with you saying that => *string might have an array prototype at the very end of it. note that sometimes we want that array and sometimes we don't.* => I am not sure if this can be done without `if` or a `ternary operator` - Lets see

Comment: ....and Offcourse there would be other solution out there - But will involve a-lot / extra lines of  `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex and replace and no need to check

```js
let value = " Have  you ever * looked*  sam [5, 6]";

const newValue = value.replace(/\[.+\]/, '');

// if there is no array in the string then it will be null or you can give it a default value
const array = JSON.parse(value.match(/\[.+\]/)) || [];

console.log(newValue);

console.log(array);
```

**Update:**

if you implement `JSON.parse()` more correctly you need to send string parameter

```js
let value = " Have  you ever * looked*  sam [5, 6]";

const newValue = value.replace(/\[.+\]/, '');

const stringify = value.match(/\[.+\]/);

// if there is no array in the string then it will be null and you can give it a default value
const array = stringify
  ? JSON.parse(stringify[0])
  : [];

console.log(newValue);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let value = " Have  you ever * looked*  sam [5, 6]";
const query = /(\[.+\])/gi
const found = value.match(query);
if (found) {
  const result = JSON.parse(found[0])
  console.log(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do no need to check if a '[' exists. The method `replace` will find it.

```js
const p = 'Have  you ever * looked*  sam [5, 6]';

var newValue = p.replace( p.substring(p.indexOf('['), p.indexOf(']')+1), '');
var array = JSON.parse( p.substring(p.indexOf('['), p.indexOf(']')+1));

console.log(newValue)
console.log(array)
```

You replace the array, from when it is opened (`p.indexOf('[')`), until it is closed (`p.indexOf(']')+1`)

Comment: if you have an array inside the array as in the following example "[5, 6, [2, 2]]" your example will not work

Comment: Ohh, ok. I forgot to mention that this code works for examples like the one you posted. Better see the other answers.